# Send GA Events using onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to send an event to Google Analytics when clicking on a specific button.

this is my button ID: `(#data_243342)`

This is my `GA` script to push on clicking on the above button.

```
onclick="dataLayer.push({"event": "eventGA","eventCategory" : "data1","eventAction" : "data-1-click","eventLabel" : "yes"})"
```

How can i pass this in a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

**With Javascript:**

```js
(function() {
  
    
  var button = document.getElementById("data_243342");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    dataLayer.push({
      "event": "eventGA",
      "eventCategory": "data1",
      "eventAction": "data-1-click",
      "eventLabel": "yes"
    });
  });
  
   
})();
```

```html
<button id="data_243342" type="button">Send</button>
```

**With jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
  
  
  $("#data_243342").on("click", function() {
    dataLayer.push({
      "event": "eventGA",
      "eventCategory": "data1",
      "eventAction": "data-1-click",
      "eventLabel": "yes"
    });
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="data_243342" type="button">Send</button>
```

> **Update:**

To add more button with the same function, you could try something like this:

**With Javascript:** By using `document.getElementsByTagName` to find the buttons to bind with the function.

```js
(function() {
  
  
  onload = function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        dataLayer.push({
          "event": "eventGA",
          "eventCategory": "data1",
          "eventAction": "data-1-click",
          "eventLabel": "yes"
        });
      });
    }
  };


})();
```

```html
<button id="data_243342" type="button">Send 1</button>
<button id="data_243343" type="button">Send 2</button>
<button id="data_243344" type="button">Send 3</button>
```

**With jQuery:** By using the #id selectors of the buttons.

```js
$(function() {

  // Set the buttons id in the jQuery function.
  $("#data_243342, #data_243343, #data_243344").on("click", function() {
    dataLayer.push({
      "event": "eventGA",
      "eventCategory": "data1",
      "eventAction": "data-1-click",
      "eventLabel": "yes"
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="data_243342" type="button">Send 1</button>
<button id="data_243343" type="button">Send 2</button>
<button id="data_243344" type="button">Send 3</button>
```

**Update:**

Another way in jQuery is by using class selectors.

```js
$(function() {

  // Every button with the btn-GA class can execute the function.
  $(".btn-GA").on("click", function() {
    dataLayer.push({
      "event": "eventGA",
      "eventCategory": "data1",
      "eventAction": "data-1-click",
      "eventLabel": "yes"
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="data_243342" class="btn-GA" type="button">Send 1</button>
<button id="data_243343" class="btn-GA" type="button">Send 2</button>
<button id="data_243344" class="btn-GA" type="button">Send 3</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, this is what i wanted. one more question, i would like to track another button. In this case i just add the script two times in the same <script> ..</script>? Because i am passing this script inside a GTM tag, so i do not want to start creating multiple tags in GTM. I would like to create a custom tag with all these event tracking scripts in it.

Comment: @99problems I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: And another way in jQuery is by using class selectors. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you, but this would not work because i would like to have my own event category and event action naming convention. I would want to be able to differentiate the click on the button, so each of them will have its own naming convention.

Comment: I think repeating the script would be the only option. do you know if i could do this in a single GTM tag?

Comment: Hmm, can you show in your question the GTM Tag? I think that is possible. We're working with javascript objects.

Comment: When i say tag, i simply mean the script you had provided me before. Because i do not have the control to edit the source code of the page that i am working on, i am adding this script in GTM as a custom JS "tag". By doing so i am able to fire this script on that page. But how could i repeat the script you gave me twice in the same "tag" but for different buttons tracking?

Comment: In these circumstances you should try to repeat the script.